# How to continue if find_element does not find anything instead of producing an error that terminates the program?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following code:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/...").text
```

However, the element I am looking for is optional. It will sometimes be present and sometimes not. I want to keep track whether it is present. If it is not present, the code should not be terminated because driver.find_element throws a the `NoSuchElementException` error. I want to code to continue.

Comment: That's precisely what [try/except](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) clause exists for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use try..except block to ignore if element not present

```
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/...").text
except:
   pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a
'try: except NoSuchElementException:' statement

Answer (score 0):

try

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/...").text
except NoSuchElementException:
    #print('no element')
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't catch the raw exception.

---

Instead handle the desired [NoSuchElementException](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47995294/7429447) to prevent leakage of the flaky exceptions as follows:

```
try:
   driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/body/...").text
except NoSuchElementException:
   pass
```